# Toggle Word Wrap in BigQuery console UI

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible?  Is it in the works?

**Update:**
I happened to notice a tooltip for Accessibility Options, I followed that and it led to a link to the [**Monaco Editor**](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor).

So I learnt that BigQuery Console UI Editor runs on the same editor as VS Code, explaining why many hotkeys are conveniently the same.
`F1` will open the Command Palette in BQ console, and when I searched this, I found that the command I am looking for, known as "**Toggle Word Wrap**" in VS Code, does not seem to be available in the BigQuery Editor's Command Palette.

So, I will leave this for the **Google Cloud BigQuery team** to respond, when/if this functionality will be supported.

Background:
*I work on vertical monitors when writing code and/or queries, it helps when the queries are long and complex*

Comment: In the legacy UI there are line wrap, you can use it by clicking in `Disable editor tabs`

Comment: what about the normal UI?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to toggle word wrap on/off in BigQuery Console UI Editor

1. Press Alt+F1 for Accessibility Options. (in Mac: option+fn+f1)
2. a tool-tip will appear
3. follow the instruction to optimize for usage with a Screen Reader. (in mac that means pressing command+E)